# International Font in XNA?

Tags: xna-4.0

I'd like to know are there some international fonts?

I mean a font for all European languages including Russia.

The question is about XNA fonts.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a Unicode font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes International Fonts will work in XNA(SpriteFont). There are international fonts scattered across the internet and there might be some on your computer.

Please visit this thread for more details:

http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/93395/609738.aspx

EDIT:

I would suggest using Segoe UI, it supports a numerous amount of languages. See the link for more details.

http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1941

Comment: I know how to use sprite fonts. I'm asking about the name of some international font

Comment: The font where will be all languages included

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1941